# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range assemble object array with formulas and values from worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Let's say I have a formula in cell A1, for example: A1 contains =B1+C1

And B1 contains the number 5

and C1 contains the number 5

And then I use the following C# to get an object array of the UsedRange in the worksheet:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;

object[,] valueArray =  (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```

ValueArray will contain 3 entries:

ValueArray[0,0]=10

ValueArray[0,1]=5

ValueArray[0,2]=5

How do I instead write the C# so that I am returned this:

ValueArray[0,0]="=B1+C1"

ValueArray[0,1]=5

ValueArray[0,2]=5

In summary, if it is a formula, I want the object array element to contain the formula, but if it is *not* a formula, I want the object array element to contain the value.

## THE SOLUTION

```
    object[,] formulaArray = (object[,]) excelRange.Formula;
    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.Value2;
```

And all formula start with "="; therefore mix the object arrays as your logic dictates.

Comment: Not completely sure, but check if there is an `excelRange.get_Formula()` method...it might also be simply `excelRange.Formula()`

Comment: something like @joseph4tw suggests should work. You should be able to access the range/cell's `.Value`, `.Value2`, `.Formula` and/or `.Formula.Text`.

Comment: I was confused by the inconsistent way to access values vs formulas. Also, "Value2" isn't meaningful. Thanks for the cookie crumbs guys.

Comment: The Excel object model has both a Value and Value2 method of the Range object: they differ in their treatment of cells formatted as dates or currency.